# Place new divs above / move old divs below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some toast notifications. I gave them a position "absolute" and want them to place themselves on their own.

New toasts should place themselves **above** the already existing ones. The old one would move down then.

So this is my important Div:

```
CreateWrapper(toastMessage, foreColor, borderColor, backgroundColorIconDiv, backgroundColorContentDiv) {
    var wrapperDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var width = 350;

    wrapperDiv.id = "toast_" + this.toastCounter;
    wrapperDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    wrapperDiv.style.left = "50%";
    wrapperDiv.style.display = "none";
    wrapperDiv.style.width = width + "px";
    wrapperDiv.style.height = "100px";
    wrapperDiv.style.border = "2px solid " + borderColor;
    wrapperDiv.style.borderRadius = "10px";
    wrapperDiv.onclick = function() {
      wrapperDiv.remove(); // Destroy the toast by clicking on it
    }
    document.body.appendChild(wrapperDiv);
  }
```

and after creating it I use this code for some animations and destroying it:

```
var thisToast = this.toastCounter - 1; // get the toast Id
$(document).find("#toast_" + thisToast)
  .fadeIn(750)
  .delay(3000)
  .fadeOut(750, function() {
    $(this).remove(); // Destroy the toast
  });
```

Here's a picture of what I am looking for

[image]

Comment: which is the question/problem ? what's happening ? please post a working snippet that replicates your problem

Comment: $('parent_el').prepend('// stuff to prepend') maybe - http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: use `document.body.appendBefore(wrapperDiv,document.body.firstChild)` instead of `document.body.appendChild(wrapperDiv);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Comment: `document.body.appendBefore(wrapperDiv,document.body.firstChi‌​ld)` is not a function. So I tried `document.body.insertBefore(wrapperDiv, document.body.firstChild);` but this didn't work. It placed all the divs on the same place

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ranubis/edit?html,js,output).

You can use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)'s grid system to make things a little easier.
You should never really use absolute layout, it makes responsive webpages impossible - take a look at what happens when you resize your browser.

You will want to have a look at the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) API.

```
var container = document.querySelector('div.container');
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

newDiv.innerHTML = "HELLO  WORLD";
container.prepend(newDiv);
```

And the accompanying HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/expect/1.20.2/expect.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    hey
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The method you are looking for is [`prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

Comment: Be aware prepend() atm is experimental as that page clearly states and may not work cross-browser. Check http://caniuse.com/#search=prepend()

Comment: @yezzz ah, you are right - must have missed that. Polyfill for IE9 +

Comment: @yezzz not a fan of jQuery - i don't tend to recommend it.

Comment: Well, everybody their own preference, but I wouldn't want to add a polyfill to my page if I already had something loaded that does the job.

Comment: Sorry, I just may use Jquery, nothing else :/